# django forms get field output in view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have model form with several fields works as expected. Now I need, for specific reasons, to get form field in view but got error `'EditPostForm' object has no attribute 'about'` when I call `mydata1 = form.about` in view. But about field exist of course. `form.data.about` also wont work etc. So how can I get it? Thanks.

Comment: it just a waste to explain, you already accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you form has instance associated to it, you can try

```
post = EditPost.objects.get(id=id)
form1 = EditPostForm(instance=post)
form1.instance.about
```

Based on your comment below if you are using [ManyToMany relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) you can get the value as

```
>>> bf = BookForm(instance=book)
>>> bf.instance.authors
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x0000000004658B38>
>>> bf.instance.authors.all() #which returns a query set of related objects
[<Author: Kotian>]
>>> bf.instance.authors.all()[0]
<Author: Kotian>
>>> bf.instance.authors.all()[0].name
u'Kotian'
```

or based on how you have defined the ManyToMany

```
>>> af = AuthorForm(instance=author)
>>> af.instance.name
u'MyName'
>>> af.instance.book_set
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x0000000004658C18>
>>> af.instance.book_set.all() # returns queryset
[<Book: Book object>, <Book: Book object>]
>>> af.instance.book_set.all()[0] #accessing first object here
<Book: Book object>
>>> af.instance.book_set.all()[0].name
u'Lepord'
```

Comment: thanks akotian but I didn't get field output. It is okay with TextFields but for ManyToMany field got `  <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0xb5704a6c>  ` also BooleanField gives just False not the widget of the form field.

Comment: @Goran, Please see my edited answer, if it helps you.
Also I did not get you comment on the BooleanField as I tried with a boolean field and it return what I expected it to return.
`>>> af.instance.title` gives me `True`

Comment: Thanks you answer to the question very well. Now I have another problem and will start new question.